# SQL join on database list

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a list of database name of my clients:

```
SELECT c.db_name FROM client c;
```

On some servers (like production server), I have all those databases, but on others (like demo server), I have only few of them.

I would like to be able to retrieve the list of clients that are on my current server with a SQL query. How can I do this with MySQL?

Here is what I tried that does not work since `SHOW DATABASES` can't be used like a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT c.db_name FROM client c INNER JOIN (SHOW DATABASES) d ON c.db_name = d.Database;
```

Comment: Look into the information_schema tables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/schemata-table.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeff has already commented about the same; you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to achieve the result you are looking for

```
SELECT c.db_name 
FROM client c 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA d
ON c.db_name = d.SCHEMA_NAME;
```

Comment: we wrote the same query at the same time ^^

Comment: @RaphaelRoyer-Rivard, didn't understood. You mean you already got the answer. That's great then.